# Custom error string display when a particular macro is called

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to stop the compilation when a specific macro is called? I mean display an error string when the user has inserted this macro in the code? Can I define a macro to be error?

Comment: You want a macro that when called will generate a compilation error? and does it have to be a specific error, or an error string from the use of the macro, or is it sufficient that there is an error?

Comment: specific error string

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any standard facility to do this, but you can try to create a syntax error in the macro expansion. You could do something like this for instance:

```
#define MYMACRO (MYMACRO: "Please don't use this macro")
```

this should always lead to a syntax error whenever `MYMACRO` is used. Notice the use of `MYMACRO` inside itself to make sure that this cannot ever compile.

One of the error messages looks like this:

```
b.c: In function ‘main’:
b.c:1:18: error: ‘MYMACRO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define MYMACRO (MYMACRO: "Please don't use this macro")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use runtime assert e.g.

```
# define C_ASSERT( ) { struct tmp { char dead[-1];};}
```

This gives negative subscript.  Also you can add a restricted constant expression, which would allow some form of testing e.g.

```
# define C_ASSERT( ) { struct tmp { char dead[-1];};}
# define C_ASSERT2( x ) { struct tmp { char dead[ (x) * 2 -1];};}

int test()
{
   C_ASSERT2( sizeof( long ) < sizeof( int ) );
   C_ASSERT();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there doesn't seem to be an obvious standard mechanism for this,  defining additional behaviour per-implementation is what the `#pragma` directive is for, and [there is a GCC/Clang pragma](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas) for this situation:

```
#pragma GCC error "Not supported"
```

While `#pragma` is a directive, it also has an operator form (defined in 6.10.9) which can be expanded from a macro and take any message given to `#pragma` as a string literal, for the exact same effect:

```
// ...which can be packaged in the operator as:
_Pragma("GCC error \"Not supported\"")
```

The `message`, `GCC warning`, `GCC error` and `GCC diagnostic` opening tokens provide various messaging options through the `pragma` mechanism, so you can do this if you can use one of those compilers or another GCC-compatible one.

---

I think technically you should be able to cause an error by expanding a macro defined like the following:

```
#define err() _Pragma("STDC this is not a valid STDC directive")
```

because

> If the preprocessing token `STDC` does immediately follow `pragma` in the directive (prior to any macro replacement), then no macro replacement is performed on the directive, and the directive shall have one of the following forms...

It seems that a `pragma` message that begins with `STDC` but is not one of the messages listed in 6.10.6 is non-conforming. So you could in theory have a macro supply a string beginning with `STDC` and then the rest of your error message to `_Pragma` for a custom error mechanism.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in practice. Clang (being what I have to test with here) will recognise that the pragma message isn't legit, but will only warn about it; even with the `-Werror` flag, it still completes processing the file before erroring out, which is probably not what you wanted it to do. Lucky there's the implementation-defined way.